# How can I avoid duplicated symbol errors when I use static libraries with Cocoapods?

Tags: duplicates, dependency-management, cocoapods

I've got a executable target called `Foobar`, a static library holding some common code called `FoobarCommon`, and a test target specifically for the common code called `FoobarCommonSpecs`.

Unsurprisingly, I have made both `Foobar` and `FoobarCommonSpecs` depend on the `FoobarCommon` library.

The `Podfile` looks something like the below:

```
target 'FoobarCommon' do
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
  ...
end

target 'Foobar' do             # links against to FoobarCommon in Xcode
   ...
end

target 'FoobarCommonSpecs' do  # links against to FoobarCommon in Xcode
  pod 'LLReactiveMatchers', :git => 'https://github.com/lawrencelomax/LLReactiveMatchers.git'
end
```

`LLReactiveMatchers` is a Pod that depends on `ReactiveCocoa`.

Note that in this situation, `ReactiveCocoa` is prsent  in both `FoobarCommon` and also in `FoobarCommonSpecs`

**The Problem**

Whenever I run `FoobarCommonSpecs`, I get many `duplicate symbol` errors for `ReactiveCocoa`.

I want to say to Cocoapods that it should just IGNORE `LLReactiveMatcher`'s dependency on `ReactiveCocoa`. It should just let Xcode do its job and it should link with the copy of `ReactiveCocoa` found in FoobarCommon. How do I do that?

Does the `link_with` directive have anything to do with anything?

Comment: I've worked around this issue by simply including all the sources of `LLReactiveMatchers` into my project sources, bypassing Cocoapods. This really isn't ideal...

Comment: I found this article useful when I ran into the problem [Duplicate Symbols when using CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1729)

Comment: Haha. Good find — I had read that page already. It offers a few hints. Many users use 'the power of Ruby' to define functions that help group up the dependencies into logical groupings.

However, doing this for multiple targets very severely increases the amount of time it takes to perform a `pod install` operation, because of many many more project files that get generated.